# Truncating a std::ostream?

Tags: c++

If I write to a `std::ostream`, I can seek with `os.setp(pos)`, allowing me to overwrite bytes in the stream, and if I write "off the end", the entire stream size (file size or stringstream size) gets longer. Is there a way to say "trim from here to EOF" to truncate?

That is

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void trimToEnd(std::ostream&) { // Trims from tellp to end.
    // What goes here?
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("foo"); // Now it's "foo"
    std::ostream& s = ss; // Just use std::ostream interface.
    s.put('x'); // Now it's "xoo"
    s.put('y'); // Now it's "xyo"
    trimToEnd(s); //  "xy"
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xoY881caK

Comment: For the specific case of string streams and strings, it would probably be easier to work directly with the strings and iterators, and then `erase` to the end once done. If the string should be written to an actual file then you can do it after truncating the string.

Comment: Totally. I was just expecting the `std::iostream` interface would let us do that, since it already gives random-access write and allows the "file" to grow as you write off the end. It seems like trimming the end would be part of that.

Comment: For actual files in the file-system, it doesn't seem like there's any kind of truncation ability in the standard stream of buffer classes. Instead write to your file normally, close it, and use OS-specific functionality to truncate the file if needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as of C++17, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file is available.